# I want to remove objects from working memory EXCEPT for one specific one

Tags: drools, rules

Using Drools 5.5.FINAL.  I have a rule that detects when there is exactly one ACTIVE Contract record from among multiple Contract records in working memory.

```
/**
 *  There is exactly ONE Active Contract
 */
rule "Exactly one ACTIVE among multiple"
salience 870
activation-group "BRValidation"
no-loop
    when 
        $bmsContract : BMSContract( STAT_CD == BMS_Contract_Status.ACTIVE.toString() )
        not BMSContract( this != $bmsContract, STAT_CD == BMS_Contract_Status.ACTIVE.toString() )
        $blueReport : BlueReport( status == null )
    then
        logger.info("Rule detected one ACTIVE record from among multiple contracts;" + " Rule=" + drools.getRule().getName());
        modify ( $blueReport ) {
            setStatus( BlueReportStatus.SUCCESSFUL.toString() ),
            setReason( "Single ACTIVE status among many contracts - that's OK"),
            appendRuleAudit(drools.getRule().getName());
        }
    end
```

What I need to do in the RHS is to remove all instances of BMSContract object except for the one that has "ACTIVE" STAT_CD.  How can I do that?

Comment: You need another rule where you select a BMSContract you want to retract. It may fire multiple times.

Comment: Right - need a little help with the match syntax... I'm guessing it involves 'forall'

Comment: Just a simple constraint `STAT_CD == BMS_Contract_Status.ACTIVE.toString()` should do.

Comment: I need to match on any BMSContract object where STAT_CD is not "ACTIVE" and retract all non-Active instances.  If I just do STAT_CD != BMS_Contract_Status.ACTIVE.toString() - will it match multiple objects and remove each one in turn?!

Comment: Yes. See the comment at the top of this list: **...rule where you select a BMSContract you want to retract. It may fire multiple times.**